# WiX Toolset - How to execute SqlStrings or SqlScripts to an already existing database?

Tags: setup-project, wix3.11

I am using WiX Toolset (v.3.11) to create a setup for a desktop application, that connects to an existing database.
During the setup I need to execute a script (or an SQL string) to create a new table.

**SOLUTION #1**

Following WiX [reference for SqlDatabase](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/sql/sqldatabase.html) element:

> Remarks.
> Nesting SqlDatabase under a Component element will result in a SqlDatabase being installed to the machine as the package is installed.
>
> **Nesting SqlDatabase under Product, Fragment, or Module results in a database "locator" record being created in the SqlDatabase table. This means that the database itself is neither installed nor uninstalled by the MSI package. It does make the database available for referencing from a SqlString or SqlScript record. This allows MSI to install SqlScripts or SqlStrings to already existing databases on the machine.** The install will fail if the database does not exist in these cases.
> The User attribute...

I have created a Fragment including the SqlDatabase tag with a nested SqlString element:

```xml
    <Wix ... xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
       <Product Id="*" ...>
          ...
       </Product>
       ...
       <Fragment Id="FRG_Database">
          <sql:SqlDatabase Id="Database_MyDB" Server="[ComputerName]" Database="MyDB" Instance="MySQLInstance">
             <sql:SqlString Id="SQL_CreateMyTable" 
                            SQL="Use MyDB
                                 IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'))
                                 BEGIN
                                   CREATE TABLE MyTable (
                                   Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
                                   Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                                   Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                                 END" ContinueOnError="yes"/>
          </sql:SqlDatabase>
          
       </Fragment>
       ...
    </Wix>
```

***PROBLEM#1:*** After rebuilding the project, I get the following error:

> [CNDL5101] The sql:SqlString element cannot be specified unless the element has a Component as an ancestor. A sql:SqlString that does not have a Component ancestor is not installed.

Nesting the SqlDatabase directly into the Product element, yelds the same error.

I am a bit confused. I know I am missing something, but I cannot understand what.

Note: Same error, if I use an SqlScript element instead of the SqlString.

**SOLUTION #2**

Then, I have tried the other way: put the SqlDatabase inside a Component element, adding the *CreateOnInstall="no"* attribute to avoid creating the database during install:

```xml
    <Wix ... xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
       <Product Id="*" ...>
          ...
       </Product>
       ...
       <Fragment Id="FRG_Database">
          <DirectoryRef Id="SQLFolder">
             <Component Id="CMP_Database_Autoruns" Guid="75FAEA47-E1E3-4A58-9528-4577968EA058" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
                <sql:SqlDatabase Id="Database_MyDB" Server="[ComputerName]" Database="MyDB" Instance="MySQLInstance" CreateOnInstall="no">
                   <sql:SqlString Id="SQL_CreateMyTable" 
                                  SQL="Use MyDB
                                       IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                                       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'))
                                       BEGIN
                                         CREATE TABLE MyTable (
                                         Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
                                         Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                                         Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                                       END" ContinueOnError="yes"/>
                </sql:SqlDatabase>
             </Component>
          </DirectoryRef>
       </Fragment>
       ...
    </Wix>
```

***PROBLEM#2:*** In this case, this is the message I receive on rebuild:

> [CNDL5102] When nested under a Component, the sql:SqlDatabase element must have one of the following attributes specified: CreateOnInstall, CreateOnUninstall, DropOnInstall or DropOnUninstall.

This last error perfectly make sense, as when the SqlDatabase is within a Component, it is supposed to be installed or uninstalled while executing the setup.

I am stuck and a bit desperate.. (googling brings not better luck).

Thanks everybody in advance. Hope someone can help me, otherwise I will have to let the application programmatically execute a script file, that to me is not an elegant solution.